# Copying schema using "db2move COPY -co " command not working

Tags: db2, oraclelinux

I am connected to database tp2 trying to copy its schema "s2" to another database tp3 by using command
{db2move tp2 COPY -sn s2 -co TARGET_DB tp3 USER db2inst1 USING password}

Error is something like this

Application code page not determined, using ANSI codepage 1208

*****  DB2MOVE  *****

Action:  COPY

Start time:  Tue Sep 15 00:26:11 2020

All schema names matching:  S2;

Connecting to database TP2 ... successful!  Server : DB2 Common Server V11.1.3

Copy schema S2 to S2 on the target database TP3

Create DMT :  "SYSTOOLS"."DMT_5f5fc3d8938d2"

Rolled back all changes from the create phase (debuginfo:140).

db2move failed with -1 (debuginfo:50).

### Files generated:

COPYSCHEMA.20200915002611.msg
COPYSCHEMA.20200915002611.ERR

Please delete these files when they are no longer needed.

**Error occured -1

End time:  Tue Sep 15 00:26:48 2020

1. I tried connect reset .
2. I also tried connecting to both databases and running the command unfortunately getting same error every time.
3. Sorry if i'm missing something obvious i am new to db2.

**COPYSCHEMA.20200915002611.ERR**

Type          : TABLE
Error Msg     : [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  "TP2HIST" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DDL           :
CREATE TABLE "S2      "."BLABLA" (
"ID" INTEGER )
IN "TP2HIST"
ORGANIZE BY ROW

**COPYSCHEMA.20200915002611.msg**

*****  DB2MOVE  *****

Action:  COPY

Start time:  Tue Sep 15 00:26:11 2020

All schema names matching:  S2;

Connecting to database TP2 ... successful!  Server : DB2 Common Server V11.1.3

Copy schema S2 to S2 on the target database TP3

Create DMT :  "SYSTOOLS"."DMT_5f5fc3d8938d2"

Rolled back all changes from the create phase (debuginfo:140).

db2move failed with -1 (debuginfo:50).

### Files generated:

COPYSCHEMA.20200915002611.msg

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question to show the error messages that are listed in the COPYSCHEMA*.msg and COPYSCHEMA*.ERR files. Lookup those error codes in the Db2 Knowledge Centre, and follow the recommended actions per the error-codes shown in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The message ""TP2HIST" is an undefined name." means that at least one tablespace is different between the source and the target database.

The tablespaces used by the source-schema(s) must **either** already exist with appropriate characteristics in the target database **OR** you tell db2move to adjust (i.e. use different tablespaces during the copy), via the `tablespace_map` option to `db2move`.

The Db2 free online documentation covers the `tablespace_map` option [examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0052064.html), and in enough [detail](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html), or you can just [create](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html) the relevant tablespace(s) in the target database with the same characteristics as exist in the source database, and grant whatever permissions are required, before you run the `db2move`.

This is simple database administration, not programming. Consult a Db2 DBA to get more details, or just study the documentation in the Knowledge Centre online in the links above and related pages.